# QT5 QWebSocket handshake fail due to packet delay

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, qt5

this is my first time at here, thanks for reading my question.

I used QT5.3.2 and QWebSocket to connect with my server, everything works fine when my server is at local. But it fails to connect after I try to connect to any other server. I have found the reason why, that is, the handshake packet can't be processed correctly, here is the QT source code.

```
void QWebSocketPrivate::processData(){

Q_ASSERT(m_pSocket);
while (m_pSocket->bytesAvailable()) {
    if (state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState)
        processHandshake(m_pSocket.data());
    else
        m_dataProcessor.process(m_pSocket.data());
    }
}

void QWebSocketPrivate::processHandshake(QTcpSocket *pSocket)

{
for(int aa=0;aa<300000000;aa++)
    continue;
......
/*parse packet header & content*/
}
```

The problem is, once there are bytes available to read in web socket, the m_pSocket->bytesAvailable() function will return true, even if these bytes are only part of the handshake packet. For example, the handshake packet looks like this (cpoy from wireshark)

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n
Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 09:16:22 GMT\r\n
Upgrade: websocket\r\n
Connection: Upgrade\r\n 
......
```

when the first line(HTTP/1.1 ...) has been read into the web socket, the m_pSocket->bytesAvailable() will return true, and the processHandshake will be invoked. But this will lead to a incomplete packet parsing in processHandshake so the connection won't be set up correctly. My workaround is adding a for loop at the beginning of processHandshake to wait for the whole packet been read into the web socket, so the parsing will succeed and the connection will set up correctly.

Is this a bug of QT and is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Sure, it may be a bug in Qt. Have you considered sending an email to the mailing lists?

Comment: OK, I will report it.

Comment: I should be fixed in 5.5.0: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40878